# Could not modify HALCON-21.11-Progress

Tags: failed-installation, halcon

I will prompt this message when I uninstall Halcon and reinstall it
Try: I manually delete the registry files, and then the installation still fails

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [Halcon manual](https://www.mvtec.com/fileadmin/Redaktion/mvtec.com/products/halcon/documentation/manuals/installation_guide.pdf), chapter 3.
You could also delete this version manually from your pc.

- Delete the '*%HALCONROOT%/HALCON-21.11-Progress*' folder.
- Then go to 'Environment variables'.
  [image: Environment variables]
- Remove these variables:
  [image: Variables]
- And remove this line -> "%HALCONROOT%\bin%HALCONARCH%" from the '*Path*' variable.
  [image: Path variable]

Comment: thank you for your reply reply，I have solved this problem.I changed the installation path to the default, and the installation was successful